# Differentiating infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series

Is this derivative correct? Does the index change when differentiating the series(increase by one)?

Given  $f(x)=\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 2^kx^k$

Then $f'(x) = \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}k2^kx^{k-1}$

and $\lim_{x\to0} f'(x) = 0$

Comment: You might try simplifying by setting the upper limit to, say, $2$ and then writing it out explicitly to discover the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct. If you look at the first term in $f(x)$, it is $2x$, after differentiating, it becomes $2$, but the first term in $\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k2^{k}x^{k-1}$ is $2\cdot 2^{2}x$, which is different. The index should be preserved as $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k2^{k}x^{k-1}$.

Comment: I see. But I still don't understand why the theorem of the term by term differentiation of power series shows that the index increases:

Comment: If the differentiated series starts with negative exponent of $x$, then you drop the index, if not, the index should be kept as the same as the previous one.